# Performance Issue using Vector3.Distance

Tags: c#, performance, unity-game-engine

I am working on a system, which is distributing Commands from a HashSet to a Player. I want to distribute a Command to the Player, who is closest to the Command.

```
void AssignCommand(Player player, HashSet<Command> commandList) {
    //Player assigned;
    float min = float.MaxValue;
    float dist;

    foreach(Command command in commandList) {
        dist = Vector3.Distance(command.Position, player.Position);
        if(dist < min) {
            //check if command already assigned to another player
            assigned = command.assigned;
            if(assigned != null) {
                //reassign when distance is smaller
                if(dist < command.Distance(assigned)) {
                    //mark previously  assigned command as unassigned
                    if(player.activeCommand != null) player.activeCommand.assigned = null;
                    player.activeCommand = command;
                    command.assigned = player;
                    min = dist;

                    assigned.activeCommand = null;
                    AssignCommand(assigned, commandList);
                }
            }
            else {
                if(player.activeCommand != null) player.activeCommand.assigned = null;
                player.activeCommand = command;
                command.assigned = player;
                min = dist;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My problem with this code is that if there are a lot of commands in the HashSet it takes quite a while and the framerate drops from ~60 to about ~30 fps on my machine. This is no surprise, because the Vector3.Distance method is just called for `(every player) * (every command)`, which is way too much. I am looking now for a way to reduce the number of calls somehow to improve the performance. Any ideas here?

I also tried running this code in a different Thread, but I gave up, because this is changing and using too many Thread Unsafe values. My latest try brought me to the check if `assigned != null` throwing an error for comparing.

I would be very grateful for any hints either improving the overall speed of this code or how to run this in a ThreadPool. If required I can also post my JobClass I created for the Thread attempt.

Comment: so you have x number of players and each player has y number of commands right? and you want to order by ... distance from some point (eg the camera)?

Comment: Oh it seems I was not clear enough here.. I have x number of players and y number of commands. Now I want to assign only one command to each player. The code above is only the part for assigning a command to one player.. This is called in a foreach over each player and some unimportant condition-checks if there are still commands and players left for assigning. The player and the command are both linked to each other). But the player assigned to a command should be the closest player to it

Comment: where do the commands come from ? can you not distribute a command as soon as its created to save on the big list of them?

Comment: They are created from an Input Controller, when the user does certain things (mouseclick) and are put into a dictionary in a command controller. The dictionary is for assigning the commands to different priorities and works as a queue.

Its not possible to distribute a command when its created, because you could create up to 1000 commands at once and there are only 9 players... The game is a voxel game with a lot of managing and strateegic influences.. So a command eg. can be to mine a certain block

Comment: hmmm ok ... this game sounds cool :) ... so you have a list of commands with a positio nand a list of players with a position and you need to somehow match them up ... interesting problem ... do they have to happen this frame or can you task out the work to a thread over say a second?

Comment: Maybe I should include the chunks and first check the commands in the chunk next to a player, before increasing the search range...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71998/discussion-between-freedom-and-wardy).

Answer (score 4):

All the threading solutions and optimizations are fine, but the biggest thing you want to keep in mind (for this and for the future) is: *Do not use `Vector3.Distance` or `Vector3.magnitude` for this, ever.* They are inefficient.

Instead, use Vector3.sqrMagnitude, which is the same thing (for distance comparison), without the `sqrt` (the most expensive part).

Another optimization is to write your own (square) distance calculation, throwing out the y value if you know you don't care about vertical distances. My distance comparison code was slow, so I tested this pretty carefully and found this is the fastest way (especially if you don't care about vertical positions): (EDIT: this was fastest in 2015. Test yourself for the fastest code on modern Unity.)

```
            tempPosition = enemy.transform.position; // declared outside the loop, but AFAIK that shouldn't make any difference
            float xD = targetPosition.x - tempPosition.x;
            float yD = targetPosition.y - tempPosition.y; // optional
            float zD = targetPosition.z - tempPosition.z;
            float dist2 = xD*xD + yD*yD + zD*zD; // or xD*xD + zD*zD
```

Edit: Another optimization (that you're likely already doing) is to only recalculate when a player has moved. I like this one because it doesn't compromise the data at all.

Comment: I think your optimization code is exactly the same as Vector2.SqrMagnitude(), so I would prefer to use that one in your case, because its already precompiled and thus should be a tiny bit faster. I need the y-value aswell, but I see your point, that in my case definitely the square magnitude is faster, because I dont need an exact distance, but only compare the distances, which works the same with the magnitudes.. Thanks for the answer - even if I dont see a huge difference using the Threads I am sure there is a difference! Maybe I revert the repo just to check it out Unthreaded.

Comment: I encourage you to do your own testing, but I posted that code because in my game it's distinctly faster than `VectorX.sqrMagnitude.` Why? Math is either faster than you think, or Mono optimizes it better than you expect. Furthermore, Unity optimization docs state that most Unity functions are C/C++, and the cross-language function call has a performance cost (so for small logic, the pre-compiled function is in fact **slower**). Keep in mind that inside a tight loop, everything counts.

Comment: Oh thats good to know!
I will definitely do that testing.. But after my last update, where I just realized that I was reassigning way too often leading to an unbelievable high recursion level I think that all of these are only tiny performance increases.. Nevertheless when you sum it up for big number of commands everything counts!
So I will do the testing and see what is fastest in my case.
And yes, I am already running that code only if there are commands queued and players without commands.

Comment: Then (to state the obvious) I hope you're ignoring the players that already have commands. That aside, at this point it may start getting harder to optimize. Want another possible hack? Surround the center point with a few concentric collider (trigger) spheres, keep track of which player is within which sphere, and only do the distance check for the players that are within the smallest occupied sphere. That way you're trading your math for the physics system. I don't know if it'll help, but it would be fun to try, no?

Comment: Yes, I create a HashSet containing all players and then remove the ones, which do have a command assigned. Then I run the code using this HashSet. AssignCommand is called for each player of that HashSet unless there are either no more players in the Set or no more Commands in the queue. After Assigning a command to each player of the Set I remove all the assigned players from the set and all assigned commands from the queue (which actually is not a queue, but a dictionary linking priorities to HashSets containing the commands)

Comment: Good idea using colliders.. I thought about comparing if they are within a chunk.. The backside of the coin is that a command can be closer to the player than all commands in the chunk/sphere, if the player is at the border of that chunk/sphere. Possible solution would be to let the spheres overlap each other, but that would require a lot of spheres.. Concerning chunks I could check the chunk & all neighbour chunks, but then I need to keep in mind that these aswell needs some hashset calculations (and then expanding the search area). So this will be slower for few Commands to check.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize there was no "center". This sounds like the perfect application for an octree--a spatial data structure based on nested regions (like cubes of cubes). I've never used one (always wanted to). This would be a great chance to play with one.

Comment: Oh sorry I think I got you wrong here... You meant to create Sphere colliders with an increasing radius at the command position and then only check for those players, which are within the closest sphere?? I will definitely try that and see if the physics engine is faster than the other code! But I think after trying all of this coming to an end and taking the fastest solution (maybe one for few commands and one for many commands) would be a good idea so that I can progress with other features ;). As said at the moment I have no more performance problems distributing the commands with my code.

Comment: Especially if you choose a good amount of sphere numbers and distances this will be fast.. Needs some tweaking although.. I think of the radius expanding logarithmically and only using about 3 or 4 spheres could be a good idea..

Comment: It might or might not be fast. I can think of problems right now. In fact, I think it's a trap. But it wouldn't hurt to try. (For one thing, you'd like to turn off colliders when the objects already have messages, but then you won't receive the OnTriggerEnter message when you turn them back on. So you need to use OnTriggerStay as well. Is that slow? Maybe. If so, you could use a helper object with a separate collider so you only need to turn it on for one update loop to get all the OnTriggerStay events, right when the object is re-enabled.)

Comment: If you used octrees for this, finding the nearest element would look like this: (I'll pretend we're in 2 dimensions): Is there a player within my square? If so, tally all players within the super-square (made up of the 4 nearest small squares to me, including the one I'm inside), and return the nearest player. If not, find where there is any player within my super-square. If so, tally all the players within my super-super-square and find the closest. If not, ... (It keeps going up the hierarchy of bigger and bigger regions, until you reach the root, at which point you would check all players).

Comment: Just realized that the backside of using the Physics version with the colliders would be that the code is no more threadable, because it is dependent on the collider objects, which are part from the Unity Engine and thus not Thread Safe... So I skipped that test for now

Answer (score 1):

I wrote my own version of System.Threading.Tasks for unity and added something like this for ordering workload based on distance from the camera.

Essentially whenever a task (or in your case command) was needed it passed off a position and the task to a TaskManager that would then each frame sort the items it had and run through them.

You could probably do the same / similar but instead of passing the command to some sort of CommmandManager like I did with a TaskManager do a lookup on creation and pass the command to the player closest to the point in question.

Most people these days are pulling their scene graphs in to something like a quad tree which should make finding the right player fairly fast then each player would be responsible for executing its own commands.

Answer (score 0):

Okay after hours working on the issue I finally found a solution to improve the performance on the one hand and make it threadable on the other hand. I had problems with the threading, because player is a Unity object.. Instead of using the player object within the task I only get its position in the Start() method. Thus I managed to make it threadable, although it seemed strange to me, that I represented the players by its positions using Vector3 now.

Improving the performance did happen by adding another Dictionary storing the already calculated distances for each player. So when reassigning a player the distance did not need to be recalculated again... I am not sure how much of performance this brought, because I tested it together with the Thread, but at least I got rid of some calls of Distance and am back at stabel 60 fps!

Furthermore I messed something up with the recursions, so that I got up to 100.000 recursions for each player.. This should NOT happen o.O. The fix was easy enough. Simply added a minCommand command, which I set during the foreach and only assign commands and touch the Sets AFTER the foreach.. I bet the code would now run like sugar even without threading...